# How to make my validator conditional based upon SSJS check (Xpages)?

Tags: validation, xpages

I have a function to call which component on my XPage performs a submit to the server:

```
//Used to check which if a component triggered an update
function submittedBy( componentId ){
    try {       
        var eventHandlerClientId = param.get( '$$xspsubmitid' );
        var eventHandlerId = @RightBack( eventHandlerClientId, ':' );
        var eventHandler = getComponent( eventHandlerId );  
        if( !eventHandler ){ 
            return false; 
        }
        var parentComponent = eventHandler.getParent();     
        if( !parentComponent ){ 
            return false;
        }       
        return ( parentComponent.getId() === componentId );  
    } catch( e ){ /*Debug.logException( e );*/ }
}
```

I have a validator which is called normally via expression language:

```
validator="#{applicationValidators.valPhone}"
```

I would like to make the validator conditioned by a check if the submit is done by the element/component with the btnSave id on it e.g.

```
<xp:this.validator><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (submittedBy('btnSave')){
    return applicationValidators.valPhone();
}}]]></xp:this.validator>
```

but the valPhone funktion expects some inputs which are injected automatically if I call the method via EL:

```
public void valPhone(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value)
```

Is there a way to include the submittedBy function in the EL or must I supply the objects when calling the function in SSJS cause for now I get the error message:

> Error while executing JavaScript action expression Script interpreter
>   error, line=2, col=38: Java method 'valPhone()' on java class
>   'org.acme.projectx.test.ApplicationValidators' not found

When I apply the objects e.g.

```
applicationValidators.valPhone(facesContext,getComponent("inpPhone"),getComponent("inpPhone").getValue());
```

it does run the validator method but does not seem to know how to handle the response (in my case I throw a ValidatorExeption with a message.

> Error while executing JavaScript action expression Script interpreter
>   error, line=4, col=31: Error calling method
>   'valPhone(com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext,
>   com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText, java.lang.String)' on java
>   class 'org.acme.projectx.test.ApplicationValidators' Phone is not
>   valid

Phone is not valid is the string message that I included in the FacesMessagge that I throw in the ValidatorExeption.

Comment: Why are you not checking the *submittedBy* component in your validator?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a totally different approach:

- create a page controller class
- call a method in the controller when the button is clicked
- do your validation based on your value(s) in that method
- if validation fails create a message in the validation error stack

I don't have a reference right now but this would be much easier to program and control in general.